# Image with a vulgarity. What to do?

Tags: discussion, flags, images, rude-or-abusive

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309499/change-font-and-label-color-swift-programmatically) was asked. At first I wanted to simply ask for more details, as it was the second question that seemed to ask about a similar programmatic change today in the topics I try to help out on.

The trouble is, it includes code. It's well-formed. It meets (at least my) standards. Then I noticed the images. (Very large, includes the last image that is offensive.)

Should I throw this to the moderators? In what way?

I'm here to help programmers, including newbies. But that final screenshot is tough to deal with. For now I guess I'll post a comment asking the OP to remove them.

Please, guide me to the proper response.

Comment: Really? Look. This site tries to be professional. Tries to act professional. I've used it for nearly a decade - first as a help to me *being* a professional, now as me *helping* other professionals. The key word is *professional*. Are you actually saying that you use this vulgarity *professionally*? (And sure, I use it too on occasion *personally*.) @Mystical, please, what's up? All I was asking for was how to handle something that - considering the question and the Q/A nature of this site - doesn't help at all. So yeah, please, tell me about your judgement of me )and not the OP).

Comment: Because you can't just "sanitize" images, I'd raise a custom flag and let a mod deal with it.  Be specific in your custom flag.

Comment: Thanks for being more specific than the first comment - which was before I could ask the OP on the question to remove the image. @Mystical may have been a "drive-by" critic who (still) may make me decide to leave this helpful site, but you've given me a chance to sleep on it. (Oh look, someone - me - is using the internet to learn something. Trust me, I'll still use this site for that.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, again, thanks. All I was doing was asking a question. One that wasn't popping up as already asked. Now I know why I don't have a Twitter account. MSO is almost as bad.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider that you may be a bit more sensitive with regard to this than the average user and simply try to ignore this. At least this is my impression/opinion.

Comment: Wow... You got one comment you didn't like, then you're ready to drop? I don't want to sound dismissive, but growing a thicker skin would be helpful :). Meta is sometimes rough around the edges

Comment: @Ctx:  I mean, there's a valid argument here.  Supposing someone posted an image laced with racial hate.  We'd want that garbage off the site quick-fast and in a hurry.

Comment: @dfd I absolutely do use this term professionally in professional contexts with my professional colleagues. Regularly. And they use it too. Regularly, and professionally. I’m not kidding, I’m not exaggerating, and no one I’ve ever heard of has ever been fired or even reprimanded over it. This may be a cultural thing, I sell software on Wall St. But if it *is* a cultural thing, tells you it’s *relative*, and so different people interpret it differently, and isn’t so black and white and ... catastrophic as you feel it to be.

Comment: @dfd Interesting how you acknowledge that you occasionally swear in professional contexts, and also feel that this user has apparently committed a great wrong upon all of society for using the word at all, and that Mysticial is somehow a bad person for not being bothered by the word in the context it was used in.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, I did not see any racial hate there, I seem to have overlooked something. Can you show up what you mean, please?

Comment: @Ctx:  It was a hypothetical.  If you live in a world/society where you don't have to experience racial hate, could you like...take me with you?  I'd love to be there.  Sounds like an amazing place.

Comment: @Makoto In this context the word was not used to insult anyone, demean anyone, etc.  It was a joke that apparently didn't land well for some people.  That doesn't mean it shouldn't be changed, but comparing it to racial slurs or hate speech is frankly uncalled for.

Comment: @Servy:  An image containing vulgarity.  I don't consider "profanity" to be "vulgarity", so I felt that the comparison was apt.  The advice I'm giving is more generic as opposed to specific.  C'mon.  Work with me here.

Comment: We are all adults here, we can handle it without blushing.  I know, those damn kids don't know how to behave themselves in public anymore.  Not actually the real problem, frustrated programmers wear their heart on their sleeve.  They can be forgiven.  If you don't want to edit it yourself then just flag it and the mod will take care of it.

Comment: @Makoto Using an analogy to “horrifying thing” for something which is not “horrifying thing” seems absurd at best and disingenuous at worst. In any case, it doesn’t advance the discussion, and so makes it somewhat difficult to “work with you” on it.  The comment was misplaced, that’s all.

Comment: Please, watch [this effing video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JfFJ7R8pDs). And think about it.

Comment: (On a side note: I just tried the "search" feature here on meta, and found it 26 times. On the main site, I found it 973 times. Happy editing.)

Comment: @Moderator who's deleting the comments here. If you're going to selectively delete comments in a way that destroys the context of the remaining comments, you might as well wipe all the comments.

Comment: Wow. Didn't mean to raise such a ruckus. I just actually *was* offended (shouldn't have been I guess) by a gigantic image that, as @Ctx stated, *did* show the issue asked. (I was much more offended by the unneeded slam by Mystical, and yes, it was needlessly deleted by a mod.) Many takes on this have been posted in the comments. I stand by my initial take - (a) it was needless, (b) not knowing what to do I decided - wrongly - to ask on MSO *before* asking the OP to remove it (and it was) and (c) now know why I do not participate on Twitter! Let me conclude....

Comment: I have much better things in life to do than argue about trivial things like this on the internet. That's why I stopped participating on a specific sports forum for my favorite team in 2007. Life is too short to care about such things. Here? It's actually the first thing I've participated in since then. I feel I've made a *positive* difference. Gave back where I gained a lot. (@Makato, good point about "vulgarity" versus "profanity" - in this comment? Positive means "constructive".) I was the last person I thought wasn't "welcoming". I need to reconsider after all this. Thanks, and peace all!

Comment: @Mysticial, you're right they might as well wipe all the comments. Few are helpful.

Comment: @Bugs et al. Feel free to flag comments you think are not helpful.

Comment: For those who are coming to this question late, the context is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lexiU.png It was taken shortly after a moderator restored the original set of comments but before they were wiped again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's several options.

- Edit the image as I did and replace it. (This is the preferred option)
- Raising a custom mod flag is acceptable. (In this case I removed the offensive wording from the image)
- Leave a comment for the author to replace the image.

If you raise a rude/abusive flag on it, it's unlikely to be marked helpful. I disputed it, so it didn't count towards a flag ban. In this instance the OP was not abusing anyone. It's not uncommon for people to leave cursing within their comments of their programs when posting here. "This is where the "blank" code doesn't work". As a rule we ask people to edit it out, rather than raise a flag.

I also left a comment for the author:

> I'd recommend you create a new image with an inoffensive word. The blank out may look confusing, as it's not clear it's a text field.

Comment: No reason for this to be downvoted? Anyway obviated it.

Comment: @DanBron there's a bunch of people who routinely downvote my meta posts.

Comment: Well, you’re a mod, I suppose it’s not news for me to tell you people on the internet are weird.

Comment: @YvetteColomb You tend to say a lot of things people disagree with or feel isn't helpful.  Just dismissing all criticism of your posts as serial voting is not an appropriate response.  Instead, you should consider *why* so many people are frequently disagreeing with the things that you're saying or otherwise feel it isn't helpful.

Comment: @YvetteColomb You could be the most downvoted user of some people because you're frequently posting things that they feel are unhelpful or that they disagree with.  Yes, some people agree with you.  That doesn't mean that no one ever disagrees with you or that they are voting on your posts without regard for their opinion of its usefulness.  **You** think they're downvoted needlessly because you think what you're saying is right.  **Other** people feel they're downvoted appropriately because they feel those posts aren't helpful.

Comment: @Servy I'm not dismissing that people disagree with some of the things I say. I'm stating a fact that I'm targeted for downvotes on meta. If it were main, they would be reversed. As it's meta we don't do that. I truly understand and accept feedback on my posts. I also call a spade a spade. I'm not the only person who is aware of this behaviour. There's no sacred rule preventing me from stating a fact like that when someone asks. Unless people don't like being called out on their behaviour.

Comment: @YvetteColomb It's not a *fact*.  It might be your *opinion* that everyone that downvotes your posts are doing so for no reason at all and that the posts are actually all great.  That's not a fact.  You don't know why people are voting how they are.  And yes, there's no sacred rule preventing you from dismissing all downvotes on your posts as serial voting rather than considering that people might disagree with the things that you're posting, but likewise, the're no sacred rule preventing others from expressing *their* opinion that you shouldn't just dismiss all criticism in that way.

Comment: This question asked literally what to do when encountering a "vulgar" image. I gave an answer of what to do, that matches [Hans Passant's advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376662/image-with-a-vulgarity-what-to-do/376664?noredirect=1#comment647274_376662) and it has 8 downvotes.

Comment: @Servy I get a lot more criticism that you do and I do take it. I do listen to feedback. I'm not saying *all* the votes are out of spite. Of course they're not. But there are some users who are prone to downvoting me. It happens with regular monotony. So don't twist what I'm saying and tell me what I think and don't think. I am introspective and seek feedback from people. I don't have to be an open book for your opinion. I don't think you've ever said a nice thing to me in all these years. And then you wonder why I don't like your feedback?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I get plenty of criticism.  And unlike you, who has the ability (which you regularly exercise, sometimes appropriately, sometimes not) to just delete any criticism of you, I have no *choice* but to take it.  I don't remember you ever saying a nice thing about me either, but that doesn't mean that I dismiss your feedback of my opinions as anything other than someone disagreeing with me on an issue, or refuse to hear them out.

Comment: @Servy I have tried to be nice to you. It's annoying to have this unspoken animosity. You think I am so blind I can't see when I've written an unpopular post? Also I cannot delete criticisms of me. The mods are not allowed to handle flags about themselves. Unless it's to mark a flag helpful and delete my own comment. If people are rude about you, you can flag it. You have as much control as I do. I have control to handle flags. That's all. As I said if there's a conflict of interest I cannot. Unless the favour is in criticism of me, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Jeremy Good to know that people think that saying people's opinions should actually be considered, and not just ignored, is grounds for ignoring people's opinions and is an indication that they just have a grudge.  Since you think this, how do you think people should express an opinion that *won't* get ignored under the assumption that it could only possibly be because of a personal grudge?

Comment: This is the whole problem. The assumption that these downvotes are because of a personal grudge. The assumption that these downvotes are because a certain user's name is attached to the answer. It is so hard to believe that two very different users can have two very different opinions? Is it so hard to believe that two different users generally disagree with each other? _"But there are some users who are prone to downvoting me."_ > Because they often disagree with your answers. I've said this before, __don't take that personally.__ It's not personal.

Comment: If this were politics, nobody would be surprised if the opposition and those in office routinely downvoted each other because of the content of their contributions (although those would also act out of spite, I guess)

Comment: [Serial downvotes are reversed in meta also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150180/213575)

Comment: There's also one thing that comes up often In these discussions (at least to my point of view). They way they are phrased, it always seems like you have knowledge of facts we don't ( for instance here 'there are some users who are prone to downvoting me' makes it sound like you see who votes on what, which is false as far as I know). It's not the first time I read a comment like that from you, which always make it sound like it comes from a position of authority ('I know I am targeted, I see data you don't'), when it's been pointed out that mods can't see that :/..

Comment: @Patrice the team can see all the votes. We can see who has voted, not on which posts. But certainly the number of up/downvotes within limits. (I can't say too much) Definitely if people are targeting a user for up and downvotes we can see that. For others and ourselves. So I'm not "imagining it" or having some "secret authority", there's a real authority in what mods can see. Mods have access to voting patterns. Maybe some people don't realise how many times they up or downvote specific users. It can add up. Can't give figures, but they're not good.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Not at all the impression I had from other posts which seem to say only  employees could see that kind of stuff. In any case, there's also an inherent bias in checking this as users on meta are either crazy active, or not at all. The cross section of active users must be huge. And since some of these users aren't always in agreement(or, more accurately said, often in disagreement), a figure like that isn't necessarily an indication of 'targetting', but more of 'we are both very active and don't agree, so we often end up voting negatively on each other's posts'

Comment: @Patrice also, many of my posts are downvoted almost immediately after posting. Sometimes so quickly that it would be impossible for them to be read. So that doesn't bode well.

Comment: @Patrice yes, I agree. If it wasn't for me saying a similar thing to someone else and being heavily downvoted where they are not. I'm going to bed now. But am happy to chat whenever you want to clarify things.

Comment: I mean... Let's call a spade a spade here. You can't know if Hans' guidance would be downvoted, since it was posted as a comment. Your answer got a net +19, even with 8 downvotes. Maybe Hans would have gotten a similar score.

Comment: Have a good night! Just waking up myself, going to spend some time with the little one and the puppy. Probably more productive for all than an exercise in 'who voted, and why' will ever be

Answer (score 15):

(Of all of the things an image can contain that are vulgar...)

Let's start with a simple heuristic.

- **Is it germane to the question?**  If it is, then because your edits are not going to be entirely neutral or run the real risk of destroying the intent of the question, flag it for moderator attention.  Be explicit about describing the issue; the image is necessary but it contains profanity which others find out-of-line with the CoC.
- **Is it *not* germane to the question?**  A simple edit will suffice to remove the image outright.  You *could* leave a comment at this point, but I find this leads to a situation in which the OP could simply start taking pot shots at *you*.  Flag for moderator attention if the situation escalates more than it should (e.g. they roll back the edit).
- **Is the image wantonly offensive (e.g. racial slurs, violence/gore, pornography?**   Flag that for moderator attention ***immediately***.  Don't use a custom message for this one; the CoC reason would be enough.  You then simply walk away from the question.  You don't need to comment or engage at *all* with the OP in this instance.  It's not worth anyone's time.

We can all be professional, but understand that sometimes, even profanity could actually be necessary to the question.

<sup>I haven't read the question in detail.  I just skimmed it on my phone.  I trust that you can discern if it's valuable and pertinent to the question.</sup>

Comment: Whether it is germane or not, it is certainly not worth to forcibly redact it and thus exercise censorship. This ultimate measure should be reserved for more serious cases.

Comment: @Ctx:  The site *is* censored, irrespective of if you like it or not.  We don't just allow anyone to say *anything* here.  However, I could also envision a scenario in which someone is developing an OCR profanity detector and it's stumbling on the word "fuck" in this explicit font, but not other example words.  Context *matters* here.

Comment: Who is "We"? You? I think, "We" don't want to restrict the freedom of speech more than absolutely necessary, regardless which "site" we are.

Comment: In the last case, it's worth noting that, if enough people flag it as spam or rude, the post gets deleted automatically without mod intervention. This is probably the fastest way to remove offensive content (at least in a way the OP can't just roll back).

Comment: @Ctx "we" is the community. The site has a [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and the purpose is to be a repository of good programming information. We aim to keep it professional. It is censored, we expect people to behave professionally, as in the workplace. This is "me" telling you this as a [moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators).

Comment: @YvetteColomb In my eyes "professionality" also includes respect for other people; changing posts unnecessarily like you did is treating them like a child, I cannot approve that.

Comment: @Ctx that's how we've been doing it for years. Don't make me go and find a meta link. I haven't had my morning coffee yet. *sigh*

Comment: On the topic of reasonable questions about such content: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6096634/4639281) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505926/profanity-regex-not-working).

Comment: @Ctx "'We' don't want to restrict the freedom of speech more than absolutely necessary" - that's a mindset that will probably lead to the most toxic of communities. There are plenty of places on the internet where there's very little censorship - [so] / [se] is not one of those places. We want people here who respect each other enough to not use offensive language, even if that means "disrespecting" those who violate that respect.

Comment: @Dukeling Ok, so you say that treating other peoples opinions and expressions with respect as far as it is reasonable leads to "most toxic communities"? This is a really problematic attitude in my opinion. The problem is exactly, that the definition of "offensive language" varies largely from person to person, so the paradigma of "minimal censorship" is imperative here.

Comment: @Ctx Only if your definition of "reasonable" is very, very different from mine.

Comment: @Dukeling Would you have edited the post in question? If your answer is "yes", then yes, it is "very, very different".

Comment: @Ctx Offensive language, wait for it, offends people. If you go with minimal censorship, that also means you care more about the person offending most people than you care about all the people they're offending.

Comment: @Dukeling I care about freedom of speech in general, not about singular people. Everyone should.

Comment: @Ctx Freedom of speech is not the same as "I should be allowed to say whatever I want on every website".

Comment: @Dukeling I am very well aware of that, thank you. If you read carefully, you will find no place where I ever said or even hinted otherwise. So what is your comment good for? If I were like the people voting up the "pro-censorship-comments" here, I would insinuate, that you are trying to attribute that claim to me and request your "offending" comment to be deleted. Lucky you, that I am not.

Comment: Why hello there long and unneeded conversation in my inbox

Comment: Nothing is needed and everything is long given the right perspective.

Comment: @Ctx If you know this isn't about freedom of speech, then I must say I'm a bit lost as for how to interpret your two earlier mentions of "freedom of speech" (especially with you being the person who brought it up).

Comment: @Makoto But yeah, it's probably about time to delete all these comments (CENSORSHIP!).

Comment: @Ctx Stack Exchange is an online network, not affiliated in any way whatsoever with any governmental body of any country that has a "freedom of speech" clause. Unless there's something in the terms that states any member is entitled to some standard of "freedom of speech," then we don't have freedom of speech here (sorry Makoto).

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the asker used names of famous scientists for testing the functionality. The first test was done with the first name of [Leonardo da Vinci](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci). The second one was done with the last name of the famous Brazilian geologist [Reinhardt Adolfo Fuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhardt_Adolfo_Fuck).

The fact that people consider his name to be a vulgarity is a pity. Fortunately, we now know that this was only a misunderstanding.

Comment: Re *"Obviously, the asker used names of famous scientists"*: How do you know that? The proper noun form was not used for the second name.

Comment: @PeterMortensen That was just a typo ;-) It *is* a surname - also that of a German artist: https://www.karlfuck.de/ . I'm occasionally amused about the attitude that some people seem to have towards their own language, and was so after reading this question (and apologies to all Germans who might feel embarrassed when reading the word "after"). Maybe we should be thankful that *language* seems to be one of our greatest problems...

Comment: I wonder if the downvoters do not recognize jokes at all or are indeed offended by humorous posts ;)

Comment: @Ctx The downvotes are justified in so far as "This answer is not useful" - for cases where such a question is justified (e.g. if someone plainly posts porn) - even though this already as been discussed and answered elsewhere. (And of course, we have to skip the discussion of what exactly constitutes "porn"...). However, the answer may be useful to make clear that the question is/was not justified *in this particular case*...