# Should disguised insulting words in a username be allowed?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, offensive, display-names, specific-user

Recently, I found a user with name [YuckFou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8087469/yuckfou). This user name is obviously (at least for me) a disguised version of the f-word, which should not be allowed in a professional context.

I flagged this user with message:

> The user name "Yuckfou" is insulting. – liliscent 18 hours ago   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

The flag was declined for "no evidence to support it".

It's indeed a tricky situation, since the f-word is misspelled, the user can argue that they genuinely meant "YuckFou" and nothing else.

But I could immediately imagine some abusive behavior if all these flags are declined as "no evidence".

- What if a user chooses a name like "FucckYou", "FuuckYou", etc.?
- What if a user deliberately misspells offensive words in comments?

In both situations, the user can argue that they don't mean to use the offensive word.

What should be the community's stance regarding misspelled/disguised offensive words?

Comment: I find that people who have a hang up over whether some arbitrary subset of words in a language are acceptable or not, or are offended and put out by seeing them, tend to be over-concerned with frivolity in general.  I think you should chill the yuck out.  Apparently, a study demonstrated that people who swear tend to be more cognitive, analytical processors, and tolerate pain more easily (up to a limit, after which excessive swearers follow the reverse trend).

Comment: @CJK One could definitely swear to their computer screen, but the username will be seen by others, and this site requires professional behavior. From your comment, I can imply that even the f-word itself should be allowed.

Comment: 80 similar displaynames: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/929111

Comment: @liliscent  Seen by others?!?  Oh no!  I think the notion of "professional" and "unprofressional" is one of those absurd, meaningless constructs—akin to religion—used purely as an exercise of control, and not because it genuinely benefits anybody, businesses, or productivity.  Yes, I think boundaries and rules are needed to promote a cohesive society; but whether or not someone chooses to use the word "Fuck" to express themselves is neither here nor there, and should really be a personal choice.  It's interesting that you couldn't bring yourself even to type it.

Comment: @rene Too many usernames to flag...

Comment: Who was insulted? Was it directed at you? Or you believe it was directed at anyone in particular? There is a difference, IMO, in something being "offensive" and in being directly "insulting". And that difference is important to the flag thresholds. I believe the flag was correctly declined, and that we should all chill out a bit.

Comment: @yivi It's directed at all the viewers of the username. It's surprising that people considered acceptable.

Comment: And using alternative, sanitized words to common "swear" words is something old as fudge (and extremely common in professional environments). I always found it amusing, but if you are going to feel personally insulted by people using these fricking harmless alternatives, heck... I guess your life must be an effing nightmare.

Comment: Contrary to what others are saying here, I find the response to your flag most unusual. Last I checked, we *do* edit out such egregious usernames as this (case in point: I reported someone for changing their username to an insult directed at me with my real name, in a language I understood, and they were suspended for it). The intent and message of such usernames is clear - "I want to flout the rules *and* be immature about it." And the rule being flouted here is that swearing in usernames is not allowed. You can swear your head off in your bio, but not your username.

Comment: It's not acceptable and it's been changed. Thanks for posting. Next time raise a mod flag and we'll attend to it. I don't understand why it was declined, we'll discuss it.

Comment: @CJK I have probably sworn most than most people on this site in my private life. I swear daily. I do not swear on here or at work or in other places where a professional attitude is required. It requires self control. Also citing latest studies that are viral on fb to make people feel better for lack of self control is not a way to convince me that people are "intelligent". What you state is viral on social media.

Comment: @Bolt The case you mention (a direct insult) is completely different from the case posited here, in my opinion. An ethnic or sexual slur, for example, would also be a completely different matter and subject to immediate removal, even if written in a non-obvious manner. In any of those cases the offense is **directed**, and intends to cause offense and harm, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: I was under the impression that naive replacements as "heck" were not flaggable. Has that changed as well? Was it always like this? Is being "immature" flaggable? Are "nicknames" and pictures supposed to be mature and professional? Should we flag user pictures that include funny animals or personal pets if we believe they are not mature enough?

Comment: @CJK You might not be offended, but if a significant number of people are that's enough reason to change it.

Comment: @yivi: "the rule being flouted here is that swearing in usernames is not allowed" It doesn't matter if it was directed at a specific person, or to the reader in general. As for immature, I don't know why you're comparing [Getting Crap Past the Radar](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GettingCrapPastTheRadar) to sharing pictures of furry animals or pets. Maybe I should've added the word "willfully" to my original comment - I didn't think I needed to be that precise, but there you go.

Comment: @Bolt I'm comparing it only because you use something as "maturity", wilful or not, as a threshold for honoring flags. Personally, I do not find mature that someone would get offended because of an obvious replacement as "darn". I was under the impression that some lattitude was given, and I find using a nickname as "FooYou" similar to someone using a monkey face as an avatar, or a flying unicorn. None of those is very _mature_, and probably not what you'd use in LiN or your resume, but they could fly here.

Comment: @Bolt Some people would class "crap" as a word not to be used in a professional environment. Would a flag on your previous comment be honored then? I'm not offended by it, and I wouldn't flag it. I'm not trying to be dense but trying to understand if the rules have changed in a way I haven't realized, of if I always misunderstood them.

Comment: @yivi it's nothing to do with being offended, it's about keeping the site clean and standards high. People want good quality posts, we also want good quality interactions.

Comment: @YvetteColomb  I was being tongue-in-cheek by citing that study that _obviously_ everyone has seen on Facebook.  Why did I join a profession with such humourless personalities in it ? I know none of us had any friends in school, and all of sudden, tech got sexy to the common folk. But we're spending our lives worrying about the small stuff, just so we can ignore the big stuff. I mean, SO is generally a pretty hostile site, and it's not the swearers at fault.

Comment: **PS.**  I think it is most certainly about being offended. That's the very core of this. _"You might not be offended, but if a significant number of people are that's enough reason to change it"_, as @DavidHeffernan said.

Comment: @CJK oh cool! kudos. I didn't realise it was a joke. I'm so used to arguing with people on meta :) Yes it's insane. I agree. I stick to myself in real life. I like to hang with my horses and my dog. Far more relaxing than with people. SO can be hostile. The flags reveal usual patterns of pile on and someone dummy spitting. *sigh* we still do better than a lot of places on the inter-webs..

Comment: @yivi: There's a difference between using words like heck and darn, and going out of your way to preserve a word or phrase that you know is offensive in order to make a point. That difference is intent. The latter is intentionally disruptive behavior meant to incite responses like this very meta thread. There's a word for this: trolling. And if someone is trolling *by* words like heck and darn, certainly they'd be subject to the same disciplinary measures. But those instances are rare, compared to this.

Comment: I see your point. I do not agree, at least not completely, but I can understand your reasoning. Thanks @Bolt for taking the time.

Comment: I think that when someone disguises a profane/vulgar name like "bolt cock" by inserting an 'l' (even though cocks, as well as asses, bitches and tits, are just *animals*!), then the name should be changed and anonymized. And good luck for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhardt_Adolfo_Fuck when trying to register here. All this has grown **so** much out of hand that I'm tempted to lean back and watch the world burn down. Maybe a better one will rise like a phoenix from the ashes. I doubt it.

Comment: @Marco13 the rules regarding usernames have been the same for years. It's just people are reacting to anything since the welcoming blog. That is what's degrading the site. People carrying on about things that need to be taken care of and making it into a big deal. Linkedin doesn't allow profane usernames. Perhaps we should introduce using real usernames like LinkedIn.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I think there's a *significant* difference between LinkedIn, whose *sole* purpose is basically connecting ("real") people for job searches, and a Q/A site, where people want to read good answers and basically don't give a  about the nickname of the user who as written it. Beyond that, I also notice that once the more "severe" problems have been leveled out, people tend to overshoot and to actively *look* for minor things that they can complain about. Every "offense" is only perceived in context. And if somebody thinks SO is "hostile", they should visit 4chan to toughen up ;-)

Comment: @Marco13 hey facebook is rough enough! I'll skip 4chan ;)

Comment: @YvetteColomb Caution: People might call you a "small, female, domesticated cat" when you say that ;-) Seriously: This is the internet. At every point in time one is just 2 clicks away from the result of writing "clicks" with a bad kerning, and 3 clicks from the most disgusting, offending and irritating things that exist on earth. We're in a pretty "safe space" here on SO, thanks to the mods. And there is enough work to do to keep the site clean. So changing usernames like the one in this question is just a Sisyphus work and essentially a waste of time, IMHO.

Comment: @Marco13 I don't think this is about people looking for increasingly minor things to complain. There being places and circumstances in which expletives are best avoided has been a commonplace piece of etiquette for ages. Yet here it suddenly becomes "censorship", and leads folks to invoke "freedom of speech" (see also: [the very similar protracted discussion from a few days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376662/2751851), which achieved nothing but getting the OP to blank their profile).

Comment: @duplode As rene showed above, there are many usernames that contain the word "fuck", the name in question *did not even contain it*, and the asker already said that it's impossible to draw a line. In the end http://www.namespedia.com/details/Yuck and http://www.namespedia.com/details/Fou are essentially legal names. We could argue about this: Would "LuckYou" be allowed? Or "YuckLou"? Are we talking about some Levenshtein distance here? There certainly are usernames that should be changed. The problem is: It's **impossible** to define a rule. Sooo... happy flagging, everyone.

Comment: (An aside: The fact that the user name has been changed, yet the original name will likely be visible in *this* question *forever*, should raise an eyebrow for everybody who thinks that what is happening here is *reasonable* in any way...)

Comment: @Marco13 On "impossible to draw a line", I actually don't agree: it is very much possible to draw a line. That line is unlikely to be expressible as an algorithmic rule, but anyway that is rarely the case when it comes to editorial judgement, which is what we do as content curators here.

Comment: @duplode You can give everybody (moderators) pens, and let each of them draw a line (preferably after some negotiation with other mods). When a penis used wisely (and I might have forgotten to hit 'space' at some point), it may be a reasonable tool. But I think that the essence of all this is: When a username is inappropriate or obviously intended to be offensive and causes several flags, one can consider changing it. (I'm strongly convinced that changing it was **not** reasonable in this case, and the bar seems to be lowered every day, but I'm not in the role of making decisions here)

Comment: What happened to diversity? If to be accepted we have to only use the "safe (nick)names", that's not diversity, that's conformity. Being intolerant of the different is exactly the opposite of a welcoming site.

Comment: Oh, btw, if that's going to be a "rule", lets just use regexes and then we have two problems instead of zero.

Comment: @Braiam ...How is this at all related to diversity?

Comment: @Rob "Diversity (politics), the political and social policy of **encouraging tolerance** for people of different backgrounds"

Comment: @Braiam I know what the word means. I still don't see how you've made the jump from "We don't accept offensive usernames" to "We're intolerant of people of different backgrounds".

Comment: @Rob please, point to the dictionary and tell me what *universally* offensive word did the username has?

Comment: @Braiam Saying we should accept behaviour because it may not be *universally* offensive is the opposite of inclusion and tolerance. For example, should we accept racism because some people are not offended by it?

Comment: @marco (about an old comment) That doesn't make much sense, in this case the user is (likely to) **intentionally** use disguised profane words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did the correct thing flagging the user name. I've pinged the mod who declined the flag about it. They're not online at present, but may make a comment or answer on here when they're back.

If a flag you think should be marked helpful is declined, you can raise another mod flag explaining why or post on meta as you have here.

In the meantime I deleted the user's username and sent them a mod message. It's not grounds for suspension. Usernames need to conform with the [ToS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) as mentioned in the following.

[What should be done about offensive names?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251682/what-should-be-done-about-offensive-names)

From [this answer:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251684/3956566)

> Pick out a post by that user (any answer or question will do) and flag
>   it for moderator attention. Pick the 'other' option and explain that
>   you find the username to be offensive. If there are no posts, you can
>   flag one of your own posts too; the idea is to drop us a message, it's
>   not about the specific post that was flagged.
>
> .../...
>
> Profile information gets more leeway when it comes to offensive
>   content (you can swear all you want in your About Me section, provided
>   it's not illegal and overtly racist), but a username is visible
>   everywhere the user posts. As such it is subject to the terms of
>   service, which require that subscriber-provided content is not
>   offensive.

Some more bedtime reading [Stack Exchange Network Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy).

Comment: Thanks. Reading the comments under this meta question has confused me a little about the community's position. I'm glad to see that username like this one is not allowed here.

Comment: @liliscent yep, that's why Boltclock and I chimed in. To try and clarify. The question was closed. I cast the 5th reopen vote. I wanted to give you a clear answer.

Comment: Can you guide me how you (the mod team)  want to handle the [really offensive names](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/929111)? Do you want multiple flags (one per user) or one flag with a link to the query or something else (like, do nothing)?

Comment: @rene a link to a query is fine. Did you look at those profiles? A certain mod cleaned those up last night when they saw your query. Click on the profiles. Also [there's this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/929122/check-for-profanity-in-usernames), piggy backed from your query.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Oh, I didn't follow any links yet, sorry about that. Good it is followed up and thanks for that. I was just wondering what the process would be if I had a bunch of them.

Comment: @rene don't be sorry. yeh I was hoping someone would do regular queries. If you want to that would be good.